# How to set defaultValue for react-select Async and not reset when onBlur at v2.0.0?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I try to apply react-select to create async selection like [the demo](https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/),
And want to add default value for the input.
As below, the default value will be clear when onBlur because onBlur will default trigger handleInputChange event with empty value.
I guess this might case by some default setting like 'onBlurResetsInput',
but 'onBlurResetsInput' props has be removed at [v2.0.0](https://deploy-preview-2289--react-select.netlify.com/upgrade-guide).
So want to know how to prevent onBlur reset, thanks.

```
import Async from 'react-select/lib/Async';
export class AsyncSelect extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    inputValue: this.props.defaultValue,
  }

  handleInputChange = (value) => {
      this.setState({
        inputValue: value,
      });
      this.props.syncOptions(value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Async
          inputValue={this.state.inputValue}
          onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
          options={this.props.options}
          onChange={(option) => this.props.selectOption(option.value)}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Has it been resolved? I need this solution as well.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `defaultInputValue={this.state.inputValue}`? You can read more about it [here](https://react-select.com/props#statemanager-props).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I try `defaultInputValue` and it will also be reset when `onblur`.

Answer (score 0):

See this ...
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2877

It is basically you have to have a state that will be populated with the default options and then add to this state on input change (In case you use multiple select), or replace the state on input change (In case you use single select)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a conditional rendering, If the component has `defaultValue` then and only then render the Select field.

Comment: No, there is the option that the select can appear as empty too